# Comment inheritance in Doxygen fortran documentation

Tags: documentation, fortran, doxygen

I am trying to write documentation for a fortran model using Doxygen. Some variables are defined in a specific module and then used in many other different modules using the `use` statement. That is I may have a f90 with the first module

```
module my_first_module

contains

subroutine my_first_subroutine (foo, bar)

use my_second_module     , only : param


... DO STUFF ...

end subroutine my_first_subroutine
end module my_first_module
```

and then a second f90 with the second module

```
module my_second_module

real(kind=8), parameter :: param = 1.

end module my_second_module
```

My question is can I produce a Doxy documentation that allow me to comment the variable `param` where I have defined it and that is inherited by the calling functions or subroutines.

The goal is to have the `param` descriptor comment in the html page that contains the documentation of `my_first_module`.

Answer (score 0):

The `use my_second_module, only : param` and the actual usage of `param` in the `function my_first_subroutine` of `my_first_module` module will automatically create a link to the source code that defines `param`.

If you want an explicit link to the doc of the variable `param`, you can add something like `@see my_second_module::param` in the documentation of `my_first_subroutine`. This will create an actual link to the doc of your variable.

Comment: It doesn't "automatically create a link to the source ", I don't know if I need to change some flags in the Doxyfile but now unless I explicitly comment `param` it is not even shown in the `my_first_module` documentation section. And the weird thing is that the call graphs are shown properly.

Comment: It is possible that you need to define some flags! but I am not expert of doxygen so I can't jelp much